# Get the count of elements in column of arrays based on commas and turning the count into its own column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which one of the columns outputs the following when I ask for unique values (I was originally thinking of manually mapping the counts if there were less combinations):

```
df.amenities.unique()
```

```
array(['{TV,Wifi,Kitchen,Elevator,Heating,Washer,"First aid kit","Fire extinguisher",Essentials,Hangers,"Hair dryer",Iron,"Laptop friendly workspace","Private entrance"}',
       '{TV,Wifi,Kitchen,"Free parking on premises","Indoor fireplace",Heating,"Family/kid friendly",Washer,"First aid kit","Fire extinguisher",Essentials,"Lock on bedroom door",Hangers,"Hair dryer",Iron,"Laptop friendly workspace","Private entrance"}'])
```

To deal with this amenities array I decided to first get rid of the quotation marks:

```
df['amenities'] = df['amenities'].str.replace('"', '')
```

My strategy was to count the number of commas that appeared in each array element, add 1 to account for the trailing missing comma and using reset_index to name the column where I want the counts to be displayed at.

```
(df['amenities'].str.count(',').add(1).sum().reset_index(name='amenities_count'))
```

Which doesn't quite work because I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'reset_index'
```

If possible could you explain why this is not a good approach and what would be a good alternative?

Thank you for your time.

To respond to Bernard:

```
Dataframe:

    Apt    Counties    amenities
    S1       C1          {TV, "Kitchen", "WiFi"}
    S1       C1          {"Hair dryer"}
    S2       C1          {"Heating", Essentials}
    S2       C2          {"Cable", Kitchen, "WiFi"}

Output:

    Apt    Counties    amenities                       amenities_counts
    S1       C1          {TV, "Kitchen", "WiFi"}        3
    S1       C1          {"Hair dryer"}                 1
    S2       C1          {"Heating", Essentials}        2
    S2       C2          {"Cable", Kitchen, "WiFi"}     3
```

Comment: Once you summed the column, you no longer have a `pd.Series` and that is why you have an error. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @BernardL I added a mock view of how the dataframe looks like and what I am intending it to look like.

Comment: What if your strings have commas in them?

Comment: @user3483203 in this case I am using the commas to count the elements, if you want to get rid of the commas and use something else for your count you could just replace the code here: ```df['amenities'] = df['amenities'].str.replace(',', '')```

Comment: I would recommend using `[ ]` for column access, instead of the dot/`.`/attribute style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your sample, counting `','` plus one and assign it to new column

```
df['amenities_count'] = df.amenities.str.count(',').add(1)    

Out[1274]:
  Apt Counties                   amenities  amenities_count
0  S1       C1     {TV, "Kitchen", "WiFi"}                3
1  S1       C1              {"Hair dryer"}                1
2  S2       C1     {"Heating", Essentials}                2
3  S2       C2  {"Cable", Kitchen, "WiFi"}                3
```

Comment: Wow, it was so simple after all, I really overcomplicated the solution to this. It works beautifully.

Comment: It happens to me from time to time, too :)

Comment: @anky_91: Thanks, bro :) Things in my life pull me away from SO lately. However, the addiction to this community keeps yanking me back :)

Comment: @AndyL. I really appreciate your sporadic return then, there is a steep curve into learning and sometimes one just gets stuck in the stupidest things. This was one of those sad examples

Comment: @bls: oh, thank you!. It's nice of you to say that! :)